# Can dagger injection done in static method?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have this network module . I want to inject Network module in static method of ErrorUtils.

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule {
    private final String END_POINT = "https://www.myurl.com/";

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
            return okHttpClient;
       }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public GsonConverterFactory getGsonConverterFactory() {
        return GsonConverterFactory.create();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Retrofit getRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient, GsonConverterFactory gsonConverterFactory) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(END_POINT)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public RetrofitService getRetrofitService(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);
    }
```

And I want  to inject this  module in static method as :

```
public class ErrorUtils {
    @Inject
    static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static RestError parseError(Response<?> response) {

        **//showing error while writing this line**

        MyApplication.getComponent().inject(ErrorUtils.class);
        Converter<ResponseBody, RestError> converter = retrofit.responseBodyConverter(RestError.class, new Annotation[0]);

        RestError error;

        try {
            error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new RestError();
        }

        return error;
    }
}
```

How can we inject module in static method ,any suggestion ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As can be seen in [Migrating from Dagger 1](http://google.github.io/dagger/dagger-1-migration.html)

> Dagger 2 ***does not*** support static injection.

Static methods and variables are generally a bad idea. In your case you could just make your `ErrorUtils` an object, e.g. with `@Singleton` scope. Then you could properly inject the service and also properly inject your `errorUtils` without the use of static calls.

If that is not an option, you can just provide a getter to your component

```
@Component interface MyComponent {
    Retrofit getRetrofit();
}
```

And then use that method to set your static variable.

Comment: "Static methods and variables are generally a bad idea"... What about public static Intent getCallingIntent()?

Comment: I want to access a Gson object there so I have to create a new instance inside off the method or use simple singleton with static method getInstance() instead of Dagger...?

Comment: @LeoDroidcoder The problem with static objects (e.g. singletons) is called Global State. It could make testing close to impossible and may lead to more confusion than necessary if you can read and write something from anywhere. Imagine you want to deserialize a `Date` object differently in 2 different places of your app, but share the same `Gson` instance. Although Gson is a harmless example with little side effects.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak what do you do when need initialization done (i.e happens only once through out the app lifecycle) like `Crashlytics.init()` etc

Comment: @Bhargav I would just put this into `onCreate` of the application

Comment: @DavidMedenjak but these are static methods that are required, arent they?, for example when you are building libraries you will need to create static methods for initialization dont you?

Comment: I tried your approach but now I have to have access to my Application class which is not available always e.g in fragments at creation and I have to tie those initializations to life cycle which isn't nice at all

Comment: Hey @DavidMedenjak, I am new in dagger, i am stuck in same situation so, please provide best possible way with code. Thanks in advanced.